# Please help me understand this proof that $e$ is transcendental

Tags: transcendental-numbers

This started with my question "[Are the sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^k}$ transcendental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461517/are-the-sums-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nk-transcendental)". 
Kunnysan suggested that I model a proof on the standard proof that 
$e$ is transcendental.

I searched for a proof and found this one:
http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math334s106/m2334.Dioph.e.pdf.

Reading this proof,
I can understand almpst all of it,
but I have one big problem:
I do not see where any property of $e$
is actually used.

I see where they assume
$\sum^d_{k=0}
a_ke^k
 = 0
$.
They then show that,
for large enough primes $p$,
a contradiction ensues.

But I do not see where any property of 
$e$ 
(such as $e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/n!$
or $e = \exp(1)$
and
$\exp(x) = \exp'(x)$)
is used.
It almost looks like this could be used
to prove *any* number
is transcendental.

I feel dense.

So,
my question is,
where in the proof
is a property of $e$ used?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't they use a property of $e$ in the very first section, where they perform the integration by parts?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I was just interpreting that as a property of $e^x$, not a property of $e$. I will meditate on this a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Where does he define what $f$ is?

Comment: Initially, $f$ is unspecified. Then this: "If f is a polynomial of degree m". In equation (4), $f$ is specified as a polynomial which depends on a large prime $p$ and $d$, the degree of the polynomial that $e$ is assumed to satisfy.

Comment: The link to the proof appears no long appears to be valid (bad URL).  Can you present the proof here or supply an alternative link?