# Closed form for the series $\sum^{\infty}_{x=2}\frac{1}{x!-1}$ and related ones

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, closed-form

Does anyone know if there a closed-form expression for:

A. $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{x=2}\frac{1}{x!-1}$

B. $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}\frac{1}{x!+1}$

C. $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}\frac{1}{x!+x}$

I guess there should be, but again, I couldn't come up with anything. Wolfram/Alpha did no help.

Comment: Why do you think there *should be* closed forms for these series?

Comment: Mathematica can't find a closed form for any of this

Comment: If you come up with an expression for B then you have one for C (factorize the denominator and then use the generating function of the sequence in B). Having said that, I think the name of the summation variable is unfortunate

Comment: The digits of B are given here: [http://oeis.org/A217702](http://oeis.org/A217702).  No closed form is given.

Comment: You may invent a special set of constants $$C_k = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!^k}$$ ($C_1,C_2$ are already given by the exponential function and the Bessel function $I_0$) and define $A,B,C$ in terms of them.

Comment: A question related to Jack's comment (though not about a closed form for these constants) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461517/269624