# Show that the sum of the next series is an irrational number $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given:  $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^2} $ 
development of the amount $1+ \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{36}+...$

Comment: The method is almost identical to that for $e$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^2}$ converges to an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367183/prove-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-converges-to-an-irrationa)

Comment: As this is a duplicate, I've added an answer to the original question. It had several already, but I added a simple argument similar to the usual treatment of $\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!^2}$ and $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k!^2}$. Then 
$$ \begin{align}0<s-s_n&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k!^2}\\&<\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)!^2(n+2)^{2k}}\\&=\frac1{(n+1)!^2}\frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+2)^2-1}\\
&=\frac1{n!^2}\frac{1+\frac1{(n+1)^2}}{(n+2)^2-1}\\
&<\frac12\cdot\frac1{n!^2}\end{align}$$
for $n\ge1$.
Thus
$$ 0< n!^2s-n!^2s_n<\frac12.$$
Here, $n!^2s_n$ is an integer. If $s=\frac ab$ is rational, then $n!^2s $ is also integer for all large enough $n$ (for example, for $n=b$). Contradiction.